# When editing attributes for a product it removes it from category in magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I'm getting **all product entity id's** via **sql** and setting an attribute is_featured to 0 then saving the product this has the added effect of removing the product from all categories. Can someone tell me why?

```
foreach( $result as $k => $row){
  $product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($row['id']);
  $product->setStoreId(0);
  $product->setIsFeatured(0);
  $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Which specific  magento 2 version are you using?

Comment: Magento version 2.1.8